# What is this tile-based game?

Tags: identify-this-game

I bought a game at a thrift store because it was not used.

It consists of 104 ivory tiles. The tiles are numbered 1 to 13, with 2 sets in red and 2 in black; and then four more sets but these are numbered 1 to 11, with 2 sets in light blue and two with the numbers in yellow.  Below each number is an indented circle.  Also, there are two other tiles with a smiling moon face on it, one face is in red the other in black, these, too, have an indented circle on them.  Included in the case that it came in were four "racks".  It appears they are to hold the tiles.

I don't play games too much but I do like them.  Does anyone have any idea what this game is?

Comment: You cannot attach images to your posts until you have a bit more reputation - mainly for reasons of countering spam.

Comment: @JonathanHobbs No, I think new users can post images now: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/195927/133299. Either way, two upvotes gets you past new user restrictions, so it should be doable. Joann, if you click edit, there'll be an insert image button in the toolbar above the text box.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It sounds like you have yourself a [Rummikub](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rummikub) set, but with the blue and yellow sets missing their 12s and 13s. The indented circles are there mainly for the benefit of distinguishing the 6 and the 9 from each other. The racks are used for resting your unplayed tiles on - played tiles are placed on the table between the players.

[image: A photo of Rummikub from Wikipedia]

## The components of Rummikub

- Numbered tiles coming in four colours: generally red, black, blue and yellow.
- Each colour has *two sets* of tiles numbered from 1 to 13.
- Two jokers. Normally these are black and red, and represented by a smiling face.
- Four racks, since it's a game for up to four players.

All in all, you should have 106 tiles: 104 numbered, and two jokers.

That said, if you *do* have 104 tiles, you should only be missing *two* tiles, not *eight*! Have you counted correctly? Try laying them out and checking.

[image: A photo of all 106 tiles]

Comment: Thank you very much, Jonathan.  That is exactly the game I have!  I'll double check to see if I miss counted or found out why it was at the Thrift Store!... Yep all the pieces are there.  I'll google to learn how to play.  Thank you again!  Happy Thanksgiving everyone!

Comment: @Joann FYI, the game pretty much still works if you remove the tiles required to balance out the colors, so you can play a game with just 1-11 in every color.

Answer (score 0):

This game is called as "OKEY".

Comment: Can you provide more detail, like an image and/or description of "OKEY", to show how it matches the one described in the question?

Comment: Okey is played with a Rummikub set (or vice versa).